# Is the Compiz widget layer still available?

Tags: 11.04, compiz, screenlets, widgets

There used to be an option to activate the Compiz widget layer in ccsm, but in Ubuntu 11.04 i can't find it anymore, is it still available? I need it for screenlets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install [compiz-plugins-extra](http://packages.ubuntu.com/compiz-plugins-extra) [image: Install compiz-plugins-extra], I believe it should be included there.

Comment: Thank you, i would never have found the solution myself.

Comment: @K.Hendrik: You're welcome :)!

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot find the package, try `compiz-fusion-plugins-extra`.